# Checking/Reading/Writing cookies in .NET, please help me understand

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

So I have never had to use cookies before but now I am making a Shopping Cart that they can keep coming back to and leaving but I want it to store what they added.

What I am wondering:

How do check if a cookie exists and then create or update it, is that the best way to think about using a cookie?

How exactly would I store the data, in particular I want to store a list of IDs like "5,6,7,8", should I just use one string for this or is there a faster/better way than reading/parsing/writing something like that? I mean I suppose I would just keep adding new_value + ',' to the end, is there an append for cookie variables?

Does the cookie have some unique identifier that I would use to be sure I don't write duplicates or something?

Note: It's easy to look up 'HOW' like for seeing the syntax but I'm really trying to grasp the 'BEST WAY' or most ideal, how it was meant to be used, or how all you programmers found is the most fruitful way to utilize them in this type of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The winning answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376333/shopping-cart-for-non-registered-users) suggests that you only store the user ID in the cookie. The rest goes in the database.

If you can consider other approaches besides cookies, many folks prefer using session over using cookies. For one thing, you don't always have a lot of room in a cookie.

Storing the shopping cart in a cookie means that you will have no record of what people were shopping for but didn't purchase.

OTOH, using the cookie is using the shoppers' storage space and preserving your own. That could be significant over time and a lot of shoppers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in the past by creating a class to manage the cookies (e.g.`CookieManager`) with static methods I passed an `HttpRequest` object to.

I was trying to solve a very similar problem, so I created a Count cookie and then a cookie which stored the information I wanted to save (in your case an ID number).  I only wanted to save the last 5 items a user viewed, so I would manage this in my `CookieManager` class, dequeuing the oldest cookie and queuing up latest.  The Count cookie kept track of how many cookies I had. Obviously, this isn't very high tech or secure, but for this project that was completely unnecessary. Anything you want to be robust should be saved on a database, or elsewhere server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I want to further explain *why* you only store a guid that maps to a userid in a cookie.  There are two main reasons:

- Performance.  As slow as it may seem to pull data from a database, you have to remember that cookie data is not free.  It has to be uploaded from the user's browser to your web server, and even high-speed broadband connections tend to have much slower upload speeds.  By contrast, your database likely has a gigabit link (sometimes even faster) directly to the web server.  So what you really want in your cookie for best performance is a guid that maps directly to the primary key of your database table.
- Security. Data in cookies is stored in a plain text file on the user's computer.  You never know where a user will access your site from; it could be a very public place that's not appropriate to keep such data.

So is there any *data* you can use cookies for directly?  As it happens, there is.  Cookies have the nice property of sticking with a particular machine and browser.  These days a lot of people will access the web from more than one place.  Perhaps a work computer, a home computer, a smart phone, a netbook...  all of which may have different screen sizes and other peculiarities.  So what you can do with a cookie is store information specific to that combination of user+location.