# How to store user shopping cart for non registered users in node eshop?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm developing an eshop boilerplate and so far only registered users can add products to their cart.
I need non registered users to be able to add products to their cart as well.
Are there any best practices?
For registered users, cart is stored in user's document in mongodb

I've checked this answer: 
[shopping cart for non registered users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376333/shopping-cart-for-non-registered-users)
but didn't help

Comment: You can try to save the cart information onto local storage. This way you won't have to worry if the user is registered or not. How ever you must validate the fields when the user checks out the product/s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to store products for 'non-registered' users in the client itself, until the cart is not use-full for server-purpose. You may start with [indexedDb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store cart-info.

And if it is required for the server to have products, then, you may assign every client who starts putting products in the carts a unique id generated by the server, store it in the local-storage, save the cart to the server using this unique id and if the client has the same unique-id stored in the local-storage, you know what cart to serve.